# Redirect Governed by email address

Tags: php, email, authentication, redirect, passwords

Let's say I get a spreadsheet with 1000 users email addresses. Each of these users should have access to one of 10 unique landing pages. The goal is to limit who can access which pages. The landing pages can have a long alpha numeric string so people won't go guessing, i.e. [www.webpage.com/34fjx098jwlknsk67](http://www.webpage.com/34fjx098jwlknsk67)

I'd like to distribute one link, say [www.meeting.com/login](http://www.meeting.com/login). Once a user enters his/her unique email address into a field and submits, the page compares that email address to a database created from the spreadsheet. The redirect should be dependent on which of the 10 landing pages is associated to that email in the database. So I guess the lookup table can be a comma delineated doc.

So the sequence as I see it is:

1. User navigates to login page
2. User enters their email address and clicks submit
3. Page sends request to webserver (I use godaddy) to compare/lookup the email address and associated redirect URL
4. Webserver sends URL back to page
5. Page redirects to URL

Is there a simple way to do this and/or an off the shelf product to create the code?
I'm not even sure what the verbiage is for a successful web search.
Can't seem to find information so I can read up on it to make an informed decision.
Thanks.

Comment: Stackoverflow is intended as an assistace site where one can get advise on specific programming issues that one might have? It is not intended as a forum or a 'show-me-the-code' page? Kindly advise what have you tried, what code have you written, what have you developed and what specific problems do you encounter. Then SO can -and will- surely assist?

Comment: I appreciate the message, I'm a novice at HTML coding, I don't have the verbiage to even discuss this properly. Not asking for someone to jump in and supply code, I just need some direction, if this forum does not cater to something like this then my bad.